# Android: How to pass the sresult of a AsyckTask to Main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I've a class implementing AsyncTask.

It computes an object (User) and I want to return that object to main (UI) thread to be passed to a new activity.

I know it is done with **Activity.runOnUiThread()** but I can't understand what to pass to this function etc? (I want to set a variable **User usr = value** , in main thread)

How should I do?

Thank you

**EDIT:
using "Vipul Shah" code I get "unexcepted close".
This is the log (from logcat):**

```
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:513)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at es.es.ValidacionThread.doInBackground(ValidacionThread.java:65)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at es.es.ValidacionThread.doInBackground(ValidacionThread.java:1)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-12 10:28:05.404: E/AndroidRuntime(1475):     ... 4 more
```

ValidacionTask full source code:

```
package es.es;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;



public class ValidacionThread extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Usuario> {

    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://webservices.pcp/";
    private final String URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/webServices/pcpWS?wsdl";
    private final String SOAPACTION = "";
    private final String METHOD = "ValidarUsuario";
    private AccesoCuentaActivity act;

    //Handler handler;

    private Context context;

    public ValidacionThread(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected Usuario doInBackground(String[] pars) {

                 String user = pars[0];
                 String password = pars[1];
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD); 
                SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                sobre.dotNet = false;       
                request.addProperty("login", user);        
                request.addProperty("password", password); 
                sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request); 

                HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);        
                try {
                    transporte.call(SOAPACTION, sobre);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                //  JOptionPane.e.printStackTrace();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                SoapObject resultado = null;
                try {
                    resultado = (SoapObject)sobre.getResponse();
                } catch (SoapFault e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Usuario usu = new Usuario();
                usu.IdUsuario= resultado.getProperty(0).toString();
                usu.Nombre = resultado.getProperty(1).toString();
                usu.Apellidos = resultado.getProperty(2).toString();
                usu.Rol = resultado.getProperty(3).toString();   
                usu.Centro=resultado.getProperty(4).toString();
                return usu;     

}
       protected void onPostExecute(Usuario usu) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("result", usu);
           context.startActivity(intent);
           super.onPostExecute(usu);

        }

       protected void onProgress(Usuario usu) {

        }

}
```

Comment: Task. Sorry,I will correct it in few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It computes an object (User) and I want to return that object to main
>   (UI) threa  to be passed to a new activity.

Computation of object should happen in `doInBackground` method and once done use `onPostExceute` method to do UI Part.

Below snippet will help you.

**Sample Activity Class.**

```
    public class HelloActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new MyTask(this).execute("");
    }


}
```

**MyTask.java**

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, String> {

        private Context context;

        public MyTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Do background operations here and once done return the result.

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // Here you will receive that result.

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("result", result);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

Comment: what should I pass as "Context context"?

Comment: and it says "startActivity(intent);" ==> this method is not defined for MyTask

Comment: thank you for help. but it still says "startActivity(intent); ==> not defined method"

Comment: of course. I solved changing startActivity(intent) with (new Activity()) startActivity(intent); . I'm trying if it works

Comment: it is launching some exception. But I don't know where. Logcat it supposed to have saved the exception but where?

Comment: I just did it ("unexpected close") ,same problem.. how could I check what's the problem?

Comment: I just edited my original thread with the mentioned error and log

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are aware with onPostExecute and onProgressUpdate which are provided us to do UI thread work..

if still want your activity in AsyncTask then can pass it in constructor I am not sure about how this practice is good and is there any long term problem with this but works fine in general........

```
public class MyAsyncTaskextends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private <YOUR>Activity mActivity;

 public MyAsyncTaskextends (<YOUR>Activity activity){
          super();
         mActivity = activity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best to do it is to use Handle object.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      User user = (User) msg.obj;
    // here is your code 
      }
};
```

And in your thread

```
msg = handler.obtainMessage();
msg.obj = user;
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

do not forget to give a link to your handler in Tasks constructor